# How do I acquire the refund permission from the seller through 3rd party permission services

Tags: authentication, paypal, permissions, chained-payments

I tried to submit and application for a market place; initially thought to be a primary receiver, and receive all the funds, after product is delivered to  make 2nd part of chained delayed transaction to the seller.

on submit/approve app, received a message from paypal:

"We would strongly suggest you to change the business model and put yourself
 as the secondary receiver and acquire the refund permission from the seller
  through 3rd party permission services."

Is it enough to check on submit app page, the checkbox from 3rd Party PermissionsRequest -> Refund a transaction on your behalf?

For being able to refund on users behalf, or should implement request permissions through API, check if seller accepted this permission, and only at that moment let it trade on platform?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes , correct you need to first edit the application for the third party permission and then implement the permission API's to get the refund permission on their behalf . This will ease your implementation otherwise they need to manually need to go to their PayPal account and assign the refund permission to the seller .

Comment: is this way good to go? -> https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/permissions-service/ht_permissions-invoice/